# R while loop not behaving as expected

Tags: r, while-loop

I need to create a sample of 30 units, calculate the batch (`lote`), units in the batch (`n`), mean (`media`), standar deviation (`sd`) and amplitude (`amplitud`), and also create a separated table that contains all the individual values of the units.

I generate the first sample

```
tabla <- c(numeric())
columnas <- c("Lote", "n", "Media", "Dt", "Amplitud")
datos <- data.frame(matrix(c(numeric),ncol = 5,nrow =0, byrow = T ))
colnames(datos) <- columnas
lote <- 0
size <- 30
z <- qt(0.975,df = 30-1)
d <- 10
so <- sqrt(var(tabla))
error <- (so/sqrt(size))
amplitud <- (2* z * error)
fila <- 1 
set.seed(37)
matriz <- matrix(c(numeric()),byrow = T, ncol = 1)

# I create the first sample:

for(i in 1:size){
  c1 <- rnorm(1,9.5 ,1)
  c2 <- rpois(1,(5*c1))
  c3 <- rexp(1,7)
  c4 <- rexp(1,16)
  c <- c1*c2 + c3*c4
  matriz <- c(matriz,c)
}
tabla <- c(matriz)
so <- sqrt(var(tabla))
error <- (so/sqrt(size))
amplitud <- (2* z * error)
datos[fila,1] <- lote
datos[fila,2] <- size
datos[fila,3] <- mean(matriz)
datos[fila,4] <- sqrt(var(matriz))
datos[fila,5] <- (2* z * error)
lote <- lote + 1
fila <- fila + 1 
size <- round(((2*z)*(so/d))^2)
```

Then I need to keep adding batches of  `size <- round(((2*z)*(so/d))^2)`, and calculate the amplitude `(2* z * error)` after each iteration. If the amplitude is `< d`, `(d <- 10)`, I need to break the loop.

I wrote this:

```
while(condicion){
  for(i in 1:size){    
    matriz <- matrix(c(numeric()),byrow = T, ncol = 1)
    for(i in 1:size){
      c1 <- rnorm(1,9.5 ,1)
      c2 <- rpois(1,(5*c1))
      c3 <- rexp(1,7)
      c4 <- rexp(1,16)
      c <- c1*c2 + c3*c4
      matriz <- c(matriz,c)
    }

    tabla <- c(matriz)
    so <- sqrt(var(tabla))
    error <- (so/sqrt(size))
    size <- round(((2*z)*(so/d))^2)
    amplitud <- round((2* z * error))
    datos[fila,1] <- lote
    datos[fila,2] <- size
    datos[fila,3] <- mean(matriz)
    datos[fila,4] <- sqrt(var(matriz))
    datos[fila,5] <- (2* z * error)
    lote <- lote + 1
    fila <- fila + 1 
  }
  if(amplitud < d){ 
    condicion <- FALSE
    break
  }
}
```

The program  gives me an output, but it should have stopped after the 5th iteration, however it keeps going and going...

```
     Lote    n    Media       Dt Amplitud
1       0   30 432.9111  90.7863 67.80033
2       1 2177  455.905 114.0621  12.5641
3       2 2197 459.2841 114.5811 10.04514
4       3 2358    455.4 118.7037 10.35908
5       4 2256 458.2974 116.1051 9.780284
6       5 2226 454.3239 115.3553 9.934368
7       6 2313 457.0264 117.5647 10.19263
```

`[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 3398 rows ]`

Why is my loop no breaking on the first occasion where `amplitud < d`?

Comment: The way your loops are structured, your outer `for` loop doesn't contain the `if` statement.  It opens the `while`, opens the outer `for`, runs the inner `for` and closes it, then loops back to the beginning of the outer `for` loop.  When the outer `for` is finished, it checks your `if`, then closes the `while`.  To fix this, you could put your `while` inside of your outer `for` loop

Comment: I wasn't expecting a reply so quickly, many many thanks!